# Xcode archive validate button greyed out

Tags: ios, xcode, software-distribution

I'm trying to upload my app to the app store. I've selected the distribution profile and code signing authority for both the app target and the project.. I have the app details all filled out in iTunes Connect and I'm ready to go..

I've built an archive of my app with no problems, all code signing seems to have gone fine.

But the 'Validate' button on the Xcode organizer is greyed out - does anyone know why this is?

I followed the instructions from the post similar to this one.. Except for the thing about 'Copy Headers' - I'm not sure how to do this. I'm using an Xcode subproject (libPD), which I've set to 'YES' for 'skip install'..

[image: Organizer screen]

--> I'm trying to copy headers from 'Public' to 'Project' for my libPD subproject, but I don't seem to have the option for this in the Build Phases.. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Subproject Build Phases]

Comment: Please show a screenshot

Comment: AHA! It's under the 'Headers' menu of my subproject's build phases.. Thanks for suggesting the other topic regarding this, I wouldn't have found it as I didn't realise there was a difference between a 'Generic Xcode Archive' and an 'iOS Archive'..